# Dynamic concerns for a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a project I needed the ability to upload video's to a video server. At first the scope was to only upload to a Kaltura video server. To enable this, I created a simple concern that added some callback methods to the model which handle the uploads.

These callback methods (specifically for Kaltura) are being loaded like so:

```
class Videofile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include KalturaBox::Entry
end
```

And they contain basics like this (simplified version):

```
module KalturaBox
  module Entry


    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do

        before_save :create_kaltura_item, on: :create

        private
          def create_kaltura_item
            puts 'create callback called'
            self.upload
          end
      end
end
```

Now the scope has broadened, and I was asked to also include Vimeo uploads as an option.

Is it possible to dynamically embed the concerns based on an attribute of the model, or should I consider using STI instead?

I was thinking about creating a drop-down called "video_type". How do I include the correct code based on that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking about creating a drop-down called "video_type". How do I include the correct code based on that attribute?

Use [conditional callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks).

```
before_save :create_kaltura_item, on: :create, if: :kaltura?

def kaltura?
  video_type == 'kaltura'
end
```

This way you can include both concerns statically.

Comment: Yes, but the code I'm including is all about Kaltura, so I don't want to make changes to that part. Is there some way in doing this from the Videofile model?

Comment: @bo-oz Well, move the definition of `kaltura?` method to Videofile then (making it another dependency of the concern)

Comment: But the Kaltura part is a gem, which I rather don't make any changes to. So is there no way to solve the entire puzzle in the original? For instance by dynamically including the correct Modules?

Comment: @bo-oz: aight, kaltura is a gem, but it doesn't contain `before_save` thingie, does it? If it does, could you point me to the code?

Comment: @bo-oz: "To enable this, I created a simple concern" - so that's __your__ concern? And nothing actually prevents you from making that change? As to "dynamically including stuff" - it depends on what your goals are. The proposed approach works. Do you want to deliver the feature or do you want to have a two weeks long session of debugging metaprogramming black magic?

Comment: No need to be all naggy about it... just wondering whether there was a more subtle approach to this. Although I can adapt this concern, I'm not able to update the Vimeo one I'm planning on using. So the question was more from a "planning ahead" perspective.

Comment: @bo-oz: in this case, look into DCI. It's all about that idea of enhancing objects with custom behaviour just for the task at hand. I don't subscribe to it, though :)

Comment: @bo-oz: also, you always can shield your code from 3rd party api by introducing a wrapper/compatibility layer.

Comment: @bo-oz To state it clearly: No, you should not try to dynamically load concerns, that is going to be an absolute nightmare and won't work easily. Use STI, or do as Sergio has indicated and allow both concerns to be loaded and conditionally enabled/disabled through callbacks and introspection.

Comment: Thanks for your advise guys!